# vba passing list of variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have already created a macro that creates individual files for me. Now having those files I have created another VBA job in outlook that will add the contact information to the e-mail, locate the needed file, and attach it to an e-mail. I need to do this to a list of about 50 different companies that I send these audits to. Currently I need to add a certain parameter to select what company I am using "V003" for example after this job is ran I go to the next one "V004" and so on.

I am looking for a way to provide VBA the list of 50 companies codes into which I have all as folders in a certain directory path. So when i kick off the job it will reference the folder named  V003 in the directory path and use that as the VendorID variable I have created then loop back to the beginning and grab the next folder name V004 in the directory path and filter though until it gets to the last one.

Unless someone else has an idea that won't make me kick of the VBA job 50 times and pass in each variable. (Currently that's what I've been doing since I created these jobs and it's still a bit time consuming)

```
Dim GlobalVarEmail As String
Dim GlobalVarVendorName As String
Dim GlobalVendorId As String
Dim GlobalMonth As String
Dim GlobalYear As String
Dim GlobalAuditDate As String

Sub SendFilesbyEmail()
'the calling method of all sub methods.
    GlobalVendorId = InputBox("What Vendor Letter are you trying to send out? (V Code: ex - V012)", "Vendor Code", "Type Here", 7500, 5000)
    GlobalMonth = InputBox("What Month are you auditing for?(ex - Jan. Feb. Mar.)", "Month", "Type Here", 7500, 5000)
    GlobalYear = InputBox("What year are you auditing for?(ex - 2016)", "Quarter", "Type Here", 7500, 5000)
    GlobalAuditDate = InputBox("What is the audit date?(ex - 20160930)", "Quarter", "Type Here", 7500, 5000)
Call openExcel(GlobalVendorId)
Call SendAuditReport
End Sub
Public Function openExcel(UserReponse) As String
'this function is used to retrieve the vendor contact e-mail
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim sourceWS As Worksheet

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With xlApp
.Visible = False
.EnableEvents = True
End With

strFile = "G:\403(b)\User Folders\Chris W\SPARK Info\Contacts.xlsx"

Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)
Set sourceWH = sourceWB.Worksheets("SPARK")
sourceWB.Activate
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=UserReponse
    Range("F1").Select
    GlobalVarEmail = Selection.End(xlDown).Value
    Range("B1").Select
    GlobalVarVendorName = Selection.End(xlDown).Value
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Function


Function SendAuditReport()
'this function will create a e-mail, (subjectline & body), attach the needed audit letter, and insert the needed vendor contact e-mail.
Dim Fname As String
Dim sAttName As String

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachments

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olMsg = olApp.CreateItem(0) ' email
Set olAtt = olMsg.Attachments

  ' send message
With olMsg
  .Subject = GlobalVarVendorName & " " & GlobalMonth & " " & GlobalYear & " SPARK Audit"
  .To = GlobalVarEmail
  .CC = "SPARK@AXA.com"
  .Attachments.Add "G:\403(b)\User Folders\Chris W\Spark Audit\" & GlobalAuditDate & "\00-Ran Reports\" & GlobalVendorId & "\SPARK Audit Report " & GlobalVarVendorName & ".xlsx"
  'you can add attachments here just type .Attachments.Add "folder path"
  .HTMLBody = "Hello, <br /><br /> Attached is the file
  '.Send
  .Display
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Arrays (param), collections, dictionaries, classes etc   Where are the 50 source codes etc. kept?  Also, you never close the excel application, so it would open 50 times, you need to hold excel at public declaration or use `getobject` as a check before `createobject`  as it's in Excel, you could just use `new excel.application`

Comment: The 50 source codes are kept in the directory path outside of the .Attachment.add code
"G:\403(b)\User Folders\Chris W\Spark Audit\" & GlobalAuditDate & "\00-Ran Reports"

Ah I didn't think about that opening up 50 times so how would you best fix that? (I'm pretty new to using objects so I'm not 100% sure how to implement what you suggested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enumerate folder names as such:

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\pathtoyourparentfolder")

For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    MsgBox objSubFolder.Name
Next objSubFolder
```

objSubFolder.Name will be the name of the folder and you can just pass this to GlobalVendorID.

Comment: Thank you so much Jacob K it worked perfectly - What I ended up doing is added the objects and set like you suggested then added the  "For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
GlobalVendorId = objSubFolder.Name
Call openExcel(GlobalVendorId)
Call SendAuditReport

Next objSubFolder"